# Sending value for every frame of Animated in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

```
Animated.timing(
        this.state.ys,
        {
            toValue: 0,
            duration: 4000,
        }
    ).start();
```

I'd like to send ys.Value to parent component every time Animated does it's thing. Is that possible ?

Answer (score 0):

Not really, not to mention that is against the React paradigm. It would be better to start your Animated.timing() from the parent component, and pass it down to your Animated component (as a style, NOT a prop).

Comment: What are the cons of interpolating a value in the parent and passing the interpolated result as a prop?

Comment: The Animated API doesn't follow React's standard render loop. It binds animated values to style properties and rerenders the components natively, outside of the traditional React render. Props only get updated when calling render(), but Animated components typically need to re-render much more than that

Comment: Actually I just added .addListener in componentDidMount and managed to send values to parent.